# How should I make sure that a `Template.autorun()` is not running?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template `timeline` where I display the current time and values generated from it. To do so, I attached a `reactiveVar` to my template and I update it in a `autorun` attached to the same template.

Here is how it looks:

```
Template.Timeline.created = function(){
  this.time = new ReactiveVar(moment(new Date().getTime()).format('dddd d MMMM YYYY - HH:mm:ss'));    
};
Template.Timeline.rendered = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.setInterval(function(){
      console.log("tick!");
      self.time.set(moment(new Date().getTime()).format('dddd d MMMM YYYY - HH:mm:ss'));
    }, 1000);
  });
};
Template.Timeline.destroyed = function(){
  console.log("template destroyed");
};
```

The problem is that even if the template is destroyed (not the same route, not displayed anymore, my `console.log("template destroyed")` has been displayed), I indefinitely get the "tick" console log as if the template was still rendered.

I obviously missed something, and I don't get what. Why is my `setInterval` still active if its template isn't?

Comment: You need to explicitly clear the `setInterval` with [Meteor.clearInterval](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_clearinterval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly clear the `setInterval` with [Meteor.clearInterval](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_clearinterval)

By the way, you don't need the `self.autorun()` either, it's redundant here. You may also find the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package useful.